# Recode variable switching the highest values to lowest (retaining the same values within variable)

Tags: r

I want to keep the same values within a variable but switch the values to another value by order. Hard to articulate, and search for. So better to provide an example. This would be the input variable

```
 var_in <- c(10, 80,  50 , 90 , 10, 80,  50 , 90 , 1)
```

So if we ordered the unique values ascending, we have 10, 50, 80 and 90. I want to switch the values, so the highest are now the lowest, thus 90 (highest) becomes 1 (lowest), and so on. This is what the variable would look like

```
 var_result <- c(80, 10, 50, 1, 80, 10, 50, 1, 90)
```

Is there a general function that can automatically do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R its common to write your own functions.
I assume its a coincidence that your desired result in the example is simply the rev() , as its not too difficult to make an example in which what you described is not simply the rev() here is my solution:

```
var_in <- c(10, 80,  50 , 90 , 10, 80,  50 , 90 )

myfunc <- function(x){
(u1 <- sort(unique(x)))
(r1 <- rev(u1))
names(u1) <- r1
unname(u1[as.character(x)])
}

(var_out <- myfunc(var_in))
```

You are advised to come up with a better name than myfunc ...

Comment: And yes it was coincidence, a provided a poor example, now edited. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Combine `rank()` and `sort()` like this:

```
x <- c(10, 80,  50 , 90 , 10, 80,  50 , 90 )
sort(x, decreasing = T)[rank(x)]
#> [1] 90 50 80 10 90 50 80 10

# the more common vector to test
x <- c(1, 5, 7, 10, 20, 2)
sort(x, decreasing = T)[rank(x)]
#> [1] 20  7  5  2  1 10
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**